# Probability with percentage

Tags: probability

I'm new at probability. Could anyone explain me how to calculate the problem below?

A recent survey revealed that 54% of 18 to 34 years olds, 33% of 35-54 years olds, and 15 % of 55+ years old own smartphone. If 9 people ages 18 to 34 are randomly selected, find the probability that no less than 7 own a 
smartphone

My problem is that th examples doesn't make sense. From the image below, how (0.3) power 2 * (1 - 0.3) power 4 = 0.324135 ???

(0.3) power 2 = 0.09

(1 - 0.3) power 4 = 0.2401

Now:
0.09 * 0.2401 = 0.021609 NOT 0.324135 ????

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Look up the binomial distribution.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: An example of how to look it up? https://lmgtfy.com/?q=binomial+distribution

Comment: I always find simple examples with coins. Nothing like my question. Thank you anyway

Comment: Hint: this is a binomial experiment.

Comment: You are flipping a coin that lands heads $54\%$ of the time.  You need $7, 8$ or $9$ heads in $9$ tries.  That should match the description of the binomial distribution you find.

Comment: I just updated the post with an example of what does make sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "biased coin" is just a metaphor for any kind of procedure you can do where you can identify two possible outcomes, and each time you do the procedure there is the same probability $p$ that you will get the "good" outcome.

"Tossing the coin" can mean you randomly select someone between the ages of 18 and 34 and ask if they have a smartphone.
"Comes up heads" can mean that they say "yes."

To interpret the examples, it's important to account for all parts of the formula.
The general formula you found (at the top of the article) is
$$
\mathrm{Pr}(X = k) = \binom nk p^k (1 - p)^k
$$
where $\displaystyle\binom nk = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$
The notation $\displaystyle\binom nk$ is called a *binomial coefficient.*
(That is why the probability distribution is called the binomial distribution.)
The notation $n!$ is a factorial; it says to take the product of the first $n$ positive integers.
Sometimes the binomial coefficient is written
$$\displaystyle\binom nk = \dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1},$$
that is, there are $k$ factors in the numerator, the largest factor being $n,$
and $k$ factors in the denominator, the largest being $k.$

So in the example where $p = 0.3$, $n = 6,$ and $k = 2,$ you are correctly calculating that
$p^k = 0.3^2 = 0.09,$ that $(1 - p)^{n - k} = (1 - 0.3)^4 = 0.2401,$
and that $p^k = (1 - p)^{n - k}= 0.3^2 (1 - 0.3)^4 = 0.021609.$
But there are three factors in the formula:
$p^k,$ $(1 - p)^{n - k},$ and (first of all!) $\displaystyle\binom nk.$
So we also need to compute 
$\displaystyle\binom nk = \displaystyle\binom 62$
and multiply $0.021609$ by that number.

---

Conceptually, the product $(1 - p)^{n - k}$ tells us the probability of a certain *sequence* of outcomes,
for example with $n = 6$ and $k = 2$ (two heads out of six)
one of the sequences is (tails, tails, heads, tails, heads, tails).
But if we are just interested in whether there were exactly two heads,
not whether they happened to occur on the third and fifth attempt,
we also want to count sequences like (heads, heads, tails, tails, tails, tails)
and (heads, tails, heads, tails, tails, tails).
Every such sequence has the same probability to occur, but each sequence is an exclusive event that prevents any other sequence from occurring,
and there are $\displaystyle\binom nk$ possible sequences of $k$
"heads" outcomes in $n$ attempts.

Hopefully if you are in a position to be asked a question like this you are taking a course in probability. You should then have a textbook or course notes containing explanations of these things, hopefully better than mine.
That is actually where to look for definitions of things such as "binomial distribution", not on the internet (even if someone snarkily tells you to "Google it").